# wrap all word occurrences from a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to wrap a word with span from the given string here's what I tried

```js
var $word = document.querySelector('div');
var $keyword = 'test';
var wrap_word = $word.textContent.replace(new RegExp('(' + $keyword + ')'), '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold;">$1</span>');
$word.innerHTML = wrap_word;
```

```html
<div>test yeah this is a test</div>
```

but only one were wrapped, the rest were not. Any help, ideas please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "global" modifier to RegEx

```
new RegExp('(' + $keyword + ')', "g");
```